# Past perfect tense different

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

It is a imagine, not reality

"My niece hates me.Because I did not take care of her when she was a child."

I know the sentence is acceptable in use of tense.

If I use present perfect

"My niece hates me.Because I have not taken care of her since she was a child."

This sentence will be wrong because the ability not to care her is still going on.I would be heratless.Because it is the usage of present perfect tence.
What I want to ask that if present perfect and past perfect are in same use that ability not to care her is still going on.if I change past tense that sentence

"My niece hated me.Because I had not been taking care of her ever since she was a child."

Is it correct?
If it is not correct how should I write this sentence in past?

Comment: "Take care of" means "to keep someone safe and provided for", or to keep someone fed and housed. That's normally a parental role. Was this something you were supposed to do for your niece, or do you maybe mean something more like "spend time with" or "bond with"?

Comment: I'm not saying your meaning is impossible, if you babysit someone you "take care of them" for that time period. It may also be that your culture expects uncles to take on more of the responsibility of raising children than mine does. I'm just not sure it's your intended meaning.

Comment: Yes, in our country uncle is specified father.in last my question I want to point out I did not take care her for many years is first and later she hated me because of my behavior is second .Is it wrong ? If I can't use past perfect, is there another meaning for past perfect?@YonKuma

Comment: [correction:  I did not take care her =  I did not take care **of** her] I will let you correct your own question because that will help you remember: to take care of someone.  You can check your grammar in general on other sites and apps, too, before posting here.

Comment: @Lambie: But as is often pointed out, we get useful information about an OP's general competence in English from "uncorrected" text. I think in this case, although the lack of ***of*** is highly noticeable to native Anglophones, it doesn't significantly hamper our ability to understand the text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Frankly, we all have our opionions. It is not about patting ourselves on the back for understanding the question. **It's about helping an OP improve his/her English**. Otherwise, we are just  ourselves, we aren't helping. What's the point of any tense if you say: take care her or him? And why not correct it in a comment? Comments are for improving questions. And yes, I  left it uncorrected so **they can improve it not us.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your niece is now 25 years old and your relationship is now good. But when she was a teenager she hated you because you neglected her as a child.

> My niece, who is now 25, hated me when she was a teenager because I **had neglected** her when she was a child. But now she understands that my job was ship captain and I was always at sea.
>
> My niece, who is now 25, hated me when she was a teenager because I **had been neglecting** her since she was a child. But now she understands that my job was ship captain and  I was always at sea.

Comment: If I use because I had neglected her since she was a child it would mean I neglected her up to she hated me and I could still neglect her at that time, it wouldn't? Because I understand that had been neglecting means temporary.@TimR

Comment: *...since she was a child* is grammatical but to my ear it sounds just a tad off. I'd want to say *ever since she was a child*.  From her perspective as a teen, your nerglect had been *ongoing* for as long as she could remember. You can express that idea with the continuous verb and/or with "*ever* since".

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that your tense is *not* correct. We usually use the simple present tense for personal emotions; if your niece **hates you** it is presumably a long-term situation, not an activity she is doing for a certain length of time like playing tennis or cooking a meal.

The rest of the sentence is rather strange. (You don't need to split it into two sentences). If you "did not take care **of** her when she was a child", presumably she is no longer a child and can take care of herself. Are you saying that you were supposed to look after your niece when she was a child but did not, or that she has special needs and *still* needs someone to 'take care of' her?

Or do you mean this?

> My niece hated me because I did not take care of her when she was a child

Comment: Yes,according to your explanation it does not need to use past perfect ,it does? Earlier time had not taken care.@Kate Bunting

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. _I had not taken care of her since she was a child_ would mean "I had taken care of her when she was a child, but had stopped doing so when she grew up".

Comment: I mean that I did not take care of her for many years when she was a child.Later when she grew up, she thought that I did not love her thats why she hated me.By the way " I had taken care of her when she was a child, but had stopped doing so when she grew up" Is there another meaning in past perfect? I was trying to point out the first action I had not taken care later she hated me for my behavior.@Kate Bunting

Comment: The past perfect tense is a verb form used to describe a past action that occurred before another past action. @Kate Bunting

Comment: Present - **My niece hates me because I did not take care of her when she was a child.** Past - **My niece hated me because I had not taken care of her when she was a child.** (the simple past tense would be OK too, as in my example.) Don't use **since** in this sentence, because that changes the meaning (you used to, but don't any longer).

Comment: If I use because I had not taken care of her since she was a child it would mean I did not take cate of her up to she hated me and I could still not take care of her at that time, it wouldn't? Thats why you are telling not to use since in that sentence.@Kate Bunting

Comment: I told you in an earlier comment what that sentence would imply - that you stopped taking care of her when she ceased to be a child.

Comment: Now I get the point.I accept that your guiding to use simple past did not take care of her as a child.By the way it is also correct that My niece hated me because I had not taken care of her when she was a child.isn't it?@Kate Bunting.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (Don't forget to leave a space after a full stop (period)!